# 403 Forbidden + Nginx + Virtual Host configuartion + NodeJS

Tags: node.js, nginx, error-handling, virtualhost, http-status-code-403

I am getting 403 Forbidden on Server virtual host configure using Nginx for NodeJS application.

Configuration file code:

```
server {
  listen 443 default_server;
  listen [::]:443 default_server;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
  root /mnt/var/www/example.com/app/public/;

  index index.html index.htm index.php;

  server_name example.com www.example.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/dygnostica_access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/dygnostica_error.log;

  location / {
    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}

server {
   listen 0.0.0.0:80;
   server_name example.com www.example.com;
   rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

I have setup all configuration based on [this](https://medium.com/@jgefroh/a-guide-to-using-nginx-for-static-websites-d96a9d034940) article.

Need help to resolve 403. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Error log says:

directory index of "/mnt/var/www/example.com/app/public/" is forbidden.

Comment: Edit your question and add relevant entries from your access log and error log. The code in your question is missing a `;` - is that just a typo in the question or the configuration?

Comment: @RichardSmith, i have added error log.
and may be i need to give specific path to this line: "root /mnt/var/www/example.com/app/public/;" but i dont know how to give exact path.

Comment: So does nginx have permission to see into that folder?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have wrong configuration for virtual host. Here is my nginx config file. I have standard PHP application (https) on main domain and node app on subdomain (running on port 3000):

```
#// virtual host for node app:
server {
  server_name node.domain.cz;
  location / {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
  }
}

#// host (for PHP app)
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain.cz www.domain.cz;
        root /var/www/domain.cz/www;
        index index.php;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi.conf;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    # ssl_certificate ...

    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

}
```

Comment: Zaruba I have also configure standard wise configuration but just need to give directory specific path to "root /mnt/var/www/example.com/app/public/" line may be.